# Redirect doesn't seem to work on G.A.E

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using Python 2.7 and Google App engine. I've written a page that redirects a user to a form after Oauth has completed. This works perfectly on localhost, but it fails when I deploy to the app engine. What am I doing wrong?

The error message I get is "404. That’s an error. The requested URL /form was not found on this server. That’s all we know."

The server logs don't show my /form request at all.

Relevant snippets follow:

1.app.yaml

```
handlers:      
- url: .*
script: public.main.app

builtins:
- remote_api: on
- admin_redirect: on
```

2.main.py

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
     ('/form?$', content.Home), 
     ('/oauthcallback?$', content.CallbackHandler),], 
debug=True)
```

3.content.py fxn for `/oauthcallback`

```
....
http = credentials.authorize(http)
self.redirect('/form')
```

Comment: What do you mean by fails? Are you getting an error message? If so, what is it? Is the script just stopping?

Comment: I've updated my question with more details

Comment: Can you share the minimun set of files so that others can reproduce?

Comment: Unrelated, but I think you want `'/form/?$'` What you have matches with or with the `m`.

Can you show your entire callback function?

Comment: @ Dave Smith: even writing '/form' changes nothing. See my code snippets below for handlers with similar syntax

Comment: @ Takashi Matsuo: content.py can be found here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5116161 main.py = https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5116169 app.yaml = https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5116179

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooray!

Thanks guys for all your help.

@Dave Smith, that syntax: '/form?$' is perfectly alright.

It turns out that '/form' is reserved by the GAE. I renamed my entry and now it works perfectly.

See: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Reserved_URLs